# PiDora PAM allows root login but sometimes deny it

Tags: linux, ssh, raspberry-pi, fedora, pam

I am working on the Raspberry Pi version of Fedora. I have to login on my device as root using sshd which works out of the box.  Sometimes (very rarely), I can't login at all and my only option is to reboot my device.

After some research, I found that PAM is not allowing my root login. Here is some logs :

```
Jul 18 05:04:49 localhost login: pam_securetty(remote:auth): access denied: tty 'pts/0' is not secure !
Jul 18 05:04:51 localhost login: pam_unix(remote:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=pts/0 ruser= rhost=::ffff:10.175.161.56  user=root
Jul 18 05:04:51 localhost login: pam_succeed_if(remote:auth): requirement "uid >= 1000" not met by user "root"
Jul 18 05:04:53 localhost login: FAILED LOGIN 1 FROM ::ffff:10.175.161.56 FOR root, Authentication failure
Jul 18 05:04:58 localhost login: pam_securetty(remote:auth): access denied: tty 'pts/0' is not secure !
Jul 18 05:04:59 localhost login: pam_unix(remote:auth): check pass; user unknown
Jul 18 05:04:59 localhost login: pam_unix(remote:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=pts/0 ruser= rhost=::ffff:10.175.161.56
```

It seems that I am not allowed to login as root. There is few thread of Stack Overflow explaining how to allow such things.

My question is that : What could possibly make pamd allow remote root login and sometimes deny it. I guess I could simply allow everything to solve my issue, but that seems like I am gonna leave an issue unresolved.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I want to add an update on this since I found the source of the issue.

Actually what causes this is a SD Card IO bottleneck.  Whenever I would use the systemctl command to stop/start MySQL, the journaling process systemd-journald would fall into an unstable state in which it would take 100% of the SD Cards write capabilities (diagnosed with iotop).  The issue here is an SD Card not available, which caused many many strange behaviours.

I haven't found the reason why systemd-journald would fall into that state, but it seems that I am not only one experiencing this issue

My solution is to mask that service : `systemctl mask systemd-journald`.

**EDIT**

This was related to corrupted files caused by delayed allocation of the ext4 filesystem. Adding `nodelalloc` to `/etc/fstab` solved many unwanted behaviour on the device.